# Serial port programming in Linux

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I want to use **RS232** port on the board to communicate with a PC. I understand that I can use **"dev/ttyS0"** for that purpose.

I can open and write data to PC by using **write()** function. But the problem is **I can't read from "dev/ttyS0".** Every time I use read function, I get "Resource temporarily unavailable". Can u guys tell me how to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 0, fd = 0, bytes = 0;
    char ch = 0;

    char buffer[10], *bufPtr;
    int nBytes = 0, tries = 0, x = 0;

    struct termios term;

    fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
        perror("Port");
    }

    if (n = tcgetattr(fd, &term) == -1)
    {
        perror("tcgetattr");
        return;
    }

    if (n = cfsetispeed(&term, B115200) == -1)
    {
        perror("cfsetispeed");
        return;
    }

    if (n = cfsetospeed(&term, B115200) == -1)
    {
        perror("cfsetospeed");
        return;
    }

    term.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    term.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    term.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    term.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    term.c_cflag |= CS8;
    term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
    term.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    term.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
    term.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; 

    if (n = tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &term) == -1)
    {
        perror("tcsetattr");
        return;
    }

    write(fd,"LINUX",5);
    perror("write");

    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);    
    perror("fcntl");
    bytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    perror("read");
    printf("Bytes : %d and data: %s\n", bytes, buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your test? Are you shortcutting pin 2 and 3 of your RS232 DB9 connector?

Otherwise `read` will always return -1 if there are no data to be read.

This is what your code is supposed to do using `O_NDELAY` flag opening the serial line.

To avoid to read if there are no data to be read, you could use [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)
In your case:

```
struct timeval tv;
fd_set rset;
int retV;
int timeout = 5000; // 5 seconds

tv.tv_usec = (timeout * 1000) % 1000000;
tv.tv_sec = timeout / 1000;

FD_ZERO ( &rset );
FD_SET (  fd, &rset );
retV = select ( fd+1, &rset, NULL, NULL, &tv );

if( retV == 0 )
{
   // timeout stuff
}
else if( retV < 0 )
{
    // Error stuff. Read errno to see what happened
}
else
{
   // read data
}
```

**EDIT**

Remove `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);` 
If you want a normal blocking read, unset that flag.

In your code you are also assuming that `read` will return all sent chars but is not true. `read` will return chars that are available to be read. This means that if you send "LINUX" a 5 times read could be requested to read all 5 chars sent.

Last thing

```
printf("Bytes : %d and data: %s\n", bytes, buffer);
```

is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of `buffer` is not a `NULL` terminated string. You could solve it looping on received chars and print it with %c format, or `NULL` terminating your buffer with:

```
if (bytes > 0)
   buffer[bytes] = '\0';
```

or

```
char stringToSend[] = "LINUX";
size_t len = strlen(stringToSend) +1 ;

write(fd,"LINUX", len);
perror("write");

size_t receivedBytes = 0;
bytes = 0;
while (receivedBytes<len)
{
   bytes = read(fd, &buffer[receivedBytes], sizeof(buffer)-1);
   perror("read");

   if (bytes > 0)
       receivedBytes += bytes;
}

printf("Bytes : %d and data: %s\n", receivedBytes, buffer);
```

Comment: Remove the code `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);` This could reset important falgs. If you want a normal blocking read, unset that flag.